# npm bcrypt wont install in EC2 bootstrap script

Tags: node.js, amazon-ec2, npm

So I am trying to install npm packages via AWS ec2 bootstrap script. Works fine generally, but for some reason bcrypt wont install. All other packages install fine.

If I ssh into the machine, I can see bcrypt didn't get installed, but I can manually install bcrypt via:

```
npm install bcrypt
```

I execute the exact same command in the bootstrapping script. Is there some reason why bcypt can't be installed outside of an interactive console?

Comment: Not sure but if you switch to "bcryptjs" since it's pure javascript it should install with no issues. "bcrypt" has native add-ons that can be more problematic.

Comment: Well that fixed it, thanks! Wish I knew I could manually install bcrypt, but couldn't do it autonomously. Oh well